# about python relative import, which is right?

Tags: python, import

I want import a class from other python file.

```
project
└───src
│   │   main.py
│   │
│   └───spam
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   spamEmail.py
│       │   ...
```

---

Now, I want to import a class named `spamEmailBayes` from `spamEmail.py` in `main.py`

Which one is the correct import? This one:

```
from .spam.spamEmail import spamEmailBayes
```

or this one:

```
from spam.spamEmail import spamEmailBayes
```

Comment: `from spam.spamEmail import spamEmailBayes`

Comment: The second version works for me. What error are you getting? Are you sure the class is defined?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: yes  I think this is ```right from spam.spamEmail import spamEmailBayes``` but, error tag in pycharm I don't konw why